# Searching multiple numerical fields Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I already have some documents indexed using more `NumericField`s per document.
Now I want to search the documents that have all fields from <-3,+3> interval e.g.:

query:  `n1=7,n2=10,n3=12` - and the search should return all documents that have numbers from intervals: `n1=<4,10>,n2=<7,13>,n3=<9,15>`.

**Question**: what analyzer do I need, how to write a query, what searcher to use?

*It's an assignment, so I can't use any other tools that are built for searching in ranges, have to use Lucene.*

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is does not require any analzer or searcher,
just need to ensure building the correct query like :-

Example 1: Or (meaning match either one of the conditions)

```
n1:(4 10) n2:(7 13) n3:(9 15)
```

Example 2: And (meaning all three parenthesis must matched)

```
+n1:(4 10) +n2:(7 13) +n3:(9 15)
```

Example 3: Range (your question sounds like a range search)

```
n1:[4 TO 10] n2:[7 TO 13] n3:[9 TO 15]
```

Example 4: And range

```
+n1:[4 TO 10] +n2:[7 TO 13] +n3:[9 TO 15]
```

Comment: I never user Java for lucene search (zero experience on Java classes). But I have an understanding on lucene schema and it's query syntax. To search numeric (range), you would need to have all n1,n2,n3 to be using integer field type. Plus the correct query syntax